# JQuery Mobile navigation broken on SSL

Tags: jquery, ssl, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using JQuery Mobile form my MVC4 mobile web page. When I'm connecting to the site for the first time and try to go to my log in page, I get an error. The same exact code working on same exact connection for desktop version. and when I visit the log in page on desktop for the first time (and confirm the unsigned certificate) I can navigate on mobile version without a problem. 
Anyone got a clue what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you make a request for the non-secure page for the first time, your server redirects you to the secure page. jQuery Mobile does not handle redirects very well, so your best best is to turn off AJAX links for that particular page - add "data-ajax='false'" attribute to the link that takes you to the log in page.